# How to move standalone protractor automation script repository to angularjs project repository?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Development code ( Angular JS)and test automation code ( Protractor) are in different repositories in my project.  Now, I am looking for the best approach to merge these two.

I am thinking to copy the test repo and put it in e2e folder of development repo and push the code. But, Can anyone please help me to understand whether this approach is fine to perform? Also, please suggest some best approach if you know.

Comment: Please take a look at this link.
https://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide If the project is on Git, consider using the submodules approach as well.

Comment: Though the link you provided not directly answered my question, I got good insight about how to do better code in protractor. I actually copied the test repo, pasted in e2e folder of dev repo and took pull request to merge it with master.